# Apache Shiro, can not pass values from login form to backing bean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, javabeans, shiro

I can not pass values from my login form to backing bean to authenticate user by apache shiro in my web app. Does anybody know why?

shiro.ini

```
 [main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsf
authc.successUrl = /pages/welcome.jsf

[users]
admin = 1234

[urls]
/login.jsf = authc
/pages/** = authc
```

login.xhtml

```
<ui:define name="content">
<div id="login_form">
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <center>
        <h1>Sign in <p:link value="or create an account" outcome="registration" style="color: #0A9CE5; text-decoration: none;" /></h1>
            <table> 
                <tr>
                    <td><p:inputText id="username" value="#{shiroLoginBean.username}" placeholder="Login" required="true" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p:password id="password" value="#{shiroLoginBean.password}" placeholder="Password" required="true" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
        <p:commandButton value="Sign in" action="#{shiroLoginBean.doLogin}" />
    </h:form>
</div>
```

BEAN:

```
    package utils.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.IncorrectCredentialsException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.LockedAccountException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UnknownAccountException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Named("shiroLoginBean")
@Stateless
@ViewScoped
public class ShiroLoginBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShiroLoginBean.class);

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public ShiroLoginBean() {

    }

    /**
     * Try and authenticate user. 
     */
    public void doLogin() {
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();   
        UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(getUsername(), getPassword());

        try {
            subject.login(token);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("pages/welcome.jsf");
        } catch (UnknownAccountException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (LockedAccountException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (AuthenticationException | IOException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } finally {
            token.clear();
        }
    }

    //~ Setters and Getters
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

Problem is on this row...
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(getUsername(), getPassword());
... getUsername and getPassword is always null. Thank you so much for answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@ViewScoped` import is wrong - since you use `@Named` (meaning its a CDI bean) you should use

```
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
```

Since you omitted a relevant scope you'll get `@Dependent` scope, which I've never seen the use for but its very short lived (inputs will be bound to one bean, but when doLogin() runs it will be in a new one).

Comment: Thanks for reaction. So I have to delete Stateless annotation? JBoss have problem with it.. but here I think Stateless have no sence.

Comment: I agree yes, no need to make it an EJB. What is the outcome?

Comment: Nothing. I just want to redirect after login by : FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("pages/welcome.jsf");

Comment: As far as I can see you don't need a bean at all (I have no experience with Shiro): http://balusc.blogspot.dk/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html#UsingAJSFForm

Comment: Yes, I need for role separation, logging etc.. after deleting stateless anotation, change of import you suggested and change of action="#{shiroLoginBean.doLogin}" to actionListener="#{shiroLoginBean.doLogin()}" I have it solved.. Jacqen is my fav char in GoT and on stack as well :) Thank you!